# Stop events from triggering after they've been triggered once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
$('body').mousemove(function() {
    $('#covering').fadeOut(500);
    $('.block div div').fadeOut(250)
    $('.block div div').css('margin-top','160px')
    $('.block div div').fadeIn(250);
});
```

Basically what I am trying to do is have have a "covering" div fade out (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055414/a-way-to-fade-in-the-background-on-load)) and have a few block elements' inner divs fade out, move silently, and fade back in for a seamless effect.

However, when this is run, every single time the mouse is moved, all of the above is run. It presents a problem as this is not what I want to happen (I want it to happen once, and that's it) and I am guessing it slows down the browser, possibly leading to a stackup.

I think I've read somewhere how to stop something from executing once it has executed once but I cannot remember it, so is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('body').one('mousemove', function() {
        $('#covering').fadeOut(500);
        $('.block div div').fadeOut(250)
        $('.block div div').css('margin-top','160px')
        $('.block div div').fadeIn(250);
});
```

More info: **http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one**

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`One` Event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one). As stated it has the following function:

> Binds a handler to one or more events to be executed once for each matched element.

I think this is what you are looking for, here is an example of the code, that you used above using the one event.

```
$('body').one("mousemove", function() {
    $('#covering').fadeOut(500);
    $('.block div div').fadeOut(250)
    $('.block div div').css('margin-top','160px')
    $('.block div div').fadeIn(250);
});
```