# Change page background when rollover an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, fade, onmouseover

I am currently using javascript for this but if you have a better solution I am all ears.  So I have my wrapper and its background and within that is all my content including a button that I want to when hovering fade to change the background of the wrapper/page.

my css looks like this

```
#wrapper {position: absolute; min-width:550px; width:100%; height:100%; background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;}
```

and then my html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
<div class="logo">
<img src="img/logo1.png" />
</div>
<div class="button">
<img src="img/dj.png" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('img/bg2.jpg','wrapper')" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('img/bg2.jpg','wrapper')"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and then my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeBgImage (image, id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.style.backgroundImage = "url("+image+")";
    }
</script>
```

So as it sits it works, it changes the background and then changes it back on mouseout, however I want it to fade in and out.  How would I go about doing this??

EDIT: attempted both solutions below, neither seem to work or apply

Comment: For mouseout your `backgroundImage` should be `none` If I understand your question correctly. If not, care to explain more?

Comment: no because there if it is none it will remove the original background image and that is not what I want to do

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice, clean way to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg" hoverImg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg">

$('body').find('*[hoverImg]').each(function(index){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.wrap('<div>')     
    $this.parent().css('width',$this.width())  
    $this.parent().css('height',$this.width())
    $this.parent().css('background-image',"url(" + $this.attr('hoverImg')+")")
        $this.hover(function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',.01)    
        },function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',1)             
        })                    
});
```

Comment: This is what I have found, but it applies to rolling over the same image in which you would like to change.  For me my image is a) set with css and b) not the image I am rolling over

Comment: Though using `jQuery`, but does the job.

Comment: You can modify the script to redefine "this" to be the target element.

Comment: I have fiddled with it but cant get it to work in the aspect of changing the background of a seperate div

Answer (score 0):

I like your solution. [Check this out](http://fragged.org/dev/changing-and-fading-body-background-image.php) for an option for the fading effect you are trying to accomplish.

Good luck!

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055432/752527 also seems like a nice clean solution.